# Пересчитать цены товара в зависимости от его количества

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь написать блок с ценами, в котором цена за единицу товара изменяется в зависимости от его количества. Вот как-то так:

```
Количество — Цена за единицу
1______________________110 ₽
10_____________________105 ₽
20_____________________100 ₽
...
Количество товаров:__
Итого:
Цена за единицу:
```

Есть необходимость написать поле ввода, в которое пользователь вводит количество товаров, и всё это на лету пересчитывается и суммируется.

Вот моя реализация:

```js
var price1 = 110,
  price2 = 105,
  price3 = 100,
  qty1 = 1,
  qty2 = 10,
  qty3 = 20;

function conversion(val) {
  var div = document.getElementById("div"),
    price = document.getElementById("price");
  if (isNaN(val)) {
    div.innerHTML = "";
    price.innerHTML = "";
  } else {
    switch (true) {
      case (val <= 0):
        {
          div.innerHTML = "";
          price.innerHTML = "";
          break;
        }
      case (val >= qty1 && val < qty2):
        {
          div.innerHTML = val * price1;
          price.innerHTML = price1;
          break;
        }
      case (val >= qty2 && val < qty3):
        {
          div.innerHTML = val * price2;
          price.innerHTML = price2;
          break;
        }
      case (val >= qty3):
        {
          div.innerHTML = val * price3;
          price.innerHTML = price3;
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1 шт. — 110 ₽</div>
  <div>10 шт. — 105 ₽</div>
  <div>20 шт. — 100 ₽</div>
</div>
<div>
  Количество товаров:
  <div>
    <input id="txt" onblur="conversion(this.value)" onchange="conversion(this.value)" onkeypress="conversion(this.value)" onkeyup="conversion(this.value)" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Итого:
  <div id="div"></div>
</div>
<div>
  Цена за шт.:
  <div id="price"></div>
</div>
```

Прошу подсказать, как это можно грамотно реализовать с учётом того, что строчек с количеством и ценой за единицу может быть от одной до бесконечности (значения берутся из базы). На ум приходит записывать цену и количество в data-артибуты и как-нибудь перебирать эти строки скриптом.

```
...
<div data-quantity="1" data-price="115" id="shop">
 <span class="quantity">1</span>
 <span class="price">115</span>
</div>
...
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял суть, но попробуйте так.

```js
var prices = {
  1: 110,
  10: 105,
  20: 100
}

var pricesDiv = document.getElementById('prices'),
  countInput = document.getElementById('count'),
  summarySpan = document.getElementById('summary'),
  priceSpan = document.getElementById('price');

for (i in prices) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = i + ' шт. — ' + prices[i] + '₽'
  pricesDiv.appendChild(div);
}

function calculate() {
  var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0
  var multiplier;
  for (i in prices) {
if (val < i) {
  if (multiplier === undefined) {
    multiplier = prices[i];
  }
  break;
}

multiplier = prices[i];
  }

  summarySpan.innerHTML = val * multiplier
  priceSpan.innerHTML = multiplier
}

countInput.addEventListener('keyup', calculate);
countInput.addEventListener('mouseup', calculate);
```

```html
<div id="prices"> </div>
<div>
  <div> Количество товаров: </div>
  <div>
<input id="count" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div> Итого: <span id="summary">0</span> </div>
<div> Цена за шт.: <span id="price">0</span> </div>
```

Вариант с `data-quantity` и `data-price`

```js
var countInput = document.getElementById('count'),
  summarySpan = document.getElementById('summary'),
  priceSpan = document.getElementById('price'),
  priceDivs = document.getElementById('prices').getElementsByTagName('div');

var prices = { };

Array.prototype.forEach.call(priceDivs, function(el) {
  prices[el.getAttribute('data-quantity')] = el.getAttribute('data-price');
})

function calculate() {
  var val = parseInt(this.value) || 0
  var multiplier;
  for (i in prices) {
if (val < i) {
  if (multiplier === undefined) {
    multiplier = prices[i];
  }
  break;
}

multiplier = prices[i];
  }


  Array.prototype.forEach.call(priceDivs, function(el) {
if (el.getAttribute('data-price') == multiplier) {
  el.style.background = "#FF0000"
} else {
  el.style.background = "none"
}
  })

  summarySpan.innerHTML = val * multiplier
  priceSpan.innerHTML = multiplier
}

countInput.addEventListener('keyup', calculate);
countInput.addEventListener('mouseup', calculate);
```

```html
<div id="prices">
  <div data-quantity="1" data-price="110">1 шт. — 110₽</div>
  <div data-quantity="10" data-price="105">10 шт. — 105₽</div>
  <div data-quantity="20" data-price="100">20 шт. — 100₽</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div> Количество товаров: </div>
  <div>
<input id="count" type="number">
  </div>
</div>
<div> Итого: <span id="summary">0</span> </div>
<div> Цена за шт.: <span id="price">0</span> </div>
```

Comment: Да, вот как раз пример с data-атрибутами — то что надо, спасибо! А вот есть ли возможность той строчке, чьей `data-quantity` попадает в значение, введённое в текстовое поле, добавить стиль/класс? Т. е. вводим число 12, и выделяется строчка с `data-quantity="10"` и т. д.

Comment: Немного подредактировал второй вариант

Comment: Спасибо! Только вот хотел бы уточнить к моему предыдущему комментарию, что выделить бы нужно ту строку, у которой `data-quantity` попадает в значение в меньшую сторону. В общем, при вводе числа 12 из примера выше, выделить нужно строку `10 шт. — 105₽`. Я попробовал `previousElementSibling`, но игнорируется последняя строка (ну и явно очевидно, что не уместен это метод :D).

Comment: Наверное я поздновато, но немного поправил код, там была маленькая логическая ошибка

Comment: Теперь всё так, спасибо большое!